# Code Wrapping, Hide/Collapse Unhide/Expand Function

Tags: feature-request

Is there a code hide/unhide function ? [not spoiler tag]

Meaning, say i have an answer with 50 lines of code and i want to collapse it to a button/icon [hide] collapses and [show] expands, to make something like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/21962/what-comes-next-in-this-binary-sequence) less abrasive and clunky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't.

This feature has been [requested before, but has been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers) (note the [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag)

On the up side, if there is too much code in your code block, it is automatically shrunk to maximum size with a scrollable block

**Example**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Inscite autem 
medicinae et gubernationis ultimum cum ultimo sapientiae comparatur. Videmusne 
ut pueri ne verberibus quidem a contemplandis rebus perquirendisque 
deterreantur? Duo enim genera quae erant, fecit tria. Bonum negas esse 
divitias, praeposìtum esse dicis? Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Multa sunt 
dicta ab antiquis de contemnendis ac despiciendis rebus humanis; Nam cui 
proposito sit conservatio sui, necesse est huic partes quoque sui caras suo 
genere laudabiles. Fortasse id optimum, sed ubi illud: Plus semper voluptatis? 
Cur, nisi quod turpis oratio est?

Animi enim quoque dolores percipiet omnibus partibus maiores quam corporis. 
Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Ergo in gubernando 
nihil, in officio plurimum interest, quo in genere peccetur. Age, inquies, ista 
parva sunt. Si verbum sequimur, primum longius verbum praepositum quam bonum. 
Quid iudicant sensus? Bona autem corporis huic sunt, quod posterius posui, 
similiora. Diodorus, eius auditor, adiungit ad honestatem vacuitatem doloris. 
Quae similitudo in genere etiam humano apparet. Roges enim Aristonem, bonane ei 
videantur haec: vacuitas doloris, divitiae, valitudo;


Equidem etiam Epicurum, in physicis quidem, Democriteum puto. Scrupulum, 
nquam, abeunti; Intrandum est igitur in rerum naturam et penitus quid ea 
postulet pervidendum; Bonum integritas corporis: misera debilitas. Bestiarum 
vero nullum iudicium puto. Primum in nostrane potestate est, quid meminerimus?


Quid de Platone aut de Democrito loquar? Non igitur potestis voluptate omnia 
dirigentes aut tueri aut retinere virtutem. Ex quo illud efficitur, qui bene 
cenent omnis libenter cenare, qui libenter, non continuo bene. Stoicos roga. 
Fortasse id optimum, sed ubi illud: Plus semper voluptatis? Sed residamus, 
inquit, si placet. Sin laboramus, quis est, qui alienae modum statuat 
industriae? Quia dolori non voluptas contraria est, sed doloris privatio.


Haeret in salebra. Cum id fugiunt, re eadem defendunt, quae Peripatetici, 
verba. In qua quid est boni praeter summam voluptatem, et eam sempiternam? Hoc 
est non modo cor non habere, sed ne palatum quidem. Hunc vos beatum; Sit hoc 
ultimum bonorum, quod nunc a me defenditur; Quid est, quod ab ea absolvi et 
perfici debeat? Qui ita affectus, beatum esse numquam probabis; Nonne videmus 
quanta perturbatio rerum omnium consequatur, quanta confusio? Odium autem et 
invidiam facile vitabis.


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Inscite autem 
medicinae et gubernationis ultimum cum ultimo sapientiae comparatur. Videmusne 
ut pueri ne verberibus quidem a contemplandis rebus perquirendisque 
deterreantur? Duo enim genera quae erant, fecit tria. Bonum negas esse 
divitias, praeposìtum esse dicis? Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Multa sunt 
dicta ab antiquis de contemnendis ac despiciendis rebus humanis; Nam cui 
proposito sit conservatio sui, necesse est huic partes quoque sui caras suo 
genere laudabiles. Fortasse id optimum, sed ubi illud: Plus semper voluptatis? 
Cur, nisi quod turpis oratio est?

Animi enim quoque dolores percipiet omnibus partibus maiores quam corporis. 
Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Ergo in gubernando 
nihil, in officio plurimum interest, quo in genere peccetur. Age, inquies, ista 
parva sunt. Si verbum sequimur, primum longius verbum praepositum quam bonum. 
Quid iudicant sensus? Bona autem corporis huic sunt, quod posterius posui, 
similiora. Diodorus, eius auditor, adiungit ad honestatem vacuitatem doloris. 
Quae similitudo in genere etiam humano apparet. Roges enim Aristonem, bonane ei 
videantur haec: vacuitas doloris, divitiae, valitudo;


Equidem etiam Epicurum, in physicis quidem, Democriteum puto. Scrupulum, 
nquam, abeunti; Intrandum est igitur in rerum naturam et penitus quid ea 
postulet pervidendum; Bonum integritas corporis: misera debilitas. Bestiarum 
vero nullum iudicium puto. Primum in nostrane potestate est, quid meminerimus?


Quid de Platone aut de Democrito loquar? Non igitur potestis voluptate omnia 
dirigentes aut tueri aut retinere virtutem. Ex quo illud efficitur, qui bene 
cenent omnis libenter cenare, qui libenter, non continuo bene. Stoicos roga. 
Fortasse id optimum, sed ubi illud: Plus semper voluptatis? Sed residamus, 
inquit, si placet. Sin laboramus, quis est, qui alienae modum statuat 
industriae? Quia dolori non voluptas contraria est, sed doloris privatio.


Haeret in salebra. Cum id fugiunt, re eadem defendunt, quae Peripatetici, 
verba. In qua quid est boni praeter summam voluptatem, et eam sempiternam? Hoc 
est non modo cor non habere, sed ne palatum quidem. Hunc vos beatum; Sit hoc 
ultimum bonorum, quod nunc a me defenditur; Quid est, quod ab ea absolvi et 
perfici debeat? Qui ita affectus, beatum esse numquam probabis; Nonne videmus 
quanta perturbatio rerum omnium consequatur, quanta confusio? Odium autem et 
invidiam facile vitabis.
```

Comment: Can that be done artificially? Also is it possible to have a resizeable window like in edit mode?

Comment: @moonbutt74 As far as I know, no.